# Two DataSets similar Rows Different Columns in DHIS2

Tags: dhis2

I am going to create two data sets in dhis2. They have similar row names (data elements) but the column names are different

```
Table 1
      col1   col2   col3
row1   1       2      3
row2   4       5      6
row3   7       8      9

Table 2
      col4   col5   col6
row1   11     12     13
row2   14     15     16
row3   17     18     19
```

How can I do this? I can only assign one category combination to the data element. It seems I can only create one table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same data elements in both data sets, but different disaggregations for those data elements, this can be done in version 2.25 and following. When assigning a data element to a data set, you can override the category combination as defined in the data element with a category combination that is specific to the data element as it is used in that data set. For details, see "Flexible disaggregation" in https://www.dhis2.org/225#general